# How can I access global variables (currentBuild, env, ...) from within a Shared Library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'd like to access a global variable like `currentBuild`, `env`, etc. from within a [shared Groovy library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

**Example 1** (works):

```
// vars/customStep.groovy
def call() {
    echo env.myParameter
}
```

**Example 2** (doesn't work):

```
// vars/customStep.groovy
class customStep implements Serializable {
    def call() {
        echo env.myParameter
    }
}
```

**Example 3** (doesn't work):

```
// src/com/acme/Lib.groovy
package com.acme
class Lib {
    def someMethod() {
        echo env.myParameter
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the variables in either case. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `env` variable from inside a class definition, Groovy will try to access a *class variable* `env`, rather than a global variable. I think you need to create a constructor and pass the `env` variable into it. For example:

```
package com.acme
class Lib {
    def env
}
```

and in your pipeline use:

```
 def library = Lib(env: env)
```

I take groovy constructor syntax from [here](http://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_initializing_beans_with_named_parameters_and_the_default_constructor)